# Billing section in checkout process loading for long time

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, onepage-checkout

I just installed a fresh magento1.9.2.3 and tried to checkout with some products in the cart.The Billing information section is just loading and not moving to next step. Someone Kindly help me to get this issue resolved.

Comment: Please disable USPS, UPS and Fedex shipping method from backend.

Comment: @KeyurShah add it as a response, you deserve your points ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please disable `USPS`, `UPS` and `Fedex` shipping method from backend [Magento trying to get `live` `shipping rate` for your order, that's why it takes too much time to load]. By default in magento setup this shipping methods are enabled.